# *TradingView Pine* Take profit alert not working

Tags: finance, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, pine-script

*I'm using Pinescript V2*
Suppose I have a TradingView Strategy script that gives me alerts to enter trades, long or short. Let's assume I'm using a regular 20/50 MA crossover for example. The script works fine and I'm receiving the alerts, but I'm trying to create a second alert to trigger only when price crosses a level x% above my buy executed order or x% below my sell executed order.

This is an example of what I tried, for 1.2% distance:

```
if buycondition and (cross(close, strategy.position_avg_price + ((strategy.position_avg_price / 100 * 1.2) * 2)))
```

And then inside the if I'm using a boolean that then triggers the alert (which works, just not when it should). So far I've only been getting an alert every time buycondition or sellcondition itself changes, the cross doesn't seem to work.

Also tried:

```
long_stop_level = na
long_stop_level := buycondition ? strategy.position_avg_price + ((strategy.position_avg_price / 100) * 1.2) : long_stop_level[1]
if (cross(high, long_stop_level))
```

With this one some of the signals are correct, but some others are not

Comment: Pine v.2 is old, full of problems and isn't supported any more. You should move to v.4.

Comment: I'm confused. As far as I know, [alerts](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/annotations/Alert_conditions.html) don't work with strategies. Am I wrong, @Michel_T.?

Comment: "While the presence of alertcondition calls in a Pine strategy script will not cause a compilation error, alerts cannot be created from them."

Comment: @BarisYakut Ou, yes, I didn't notice it's strategy. Yes, alerts on strategies don't work yet. It's planned, but most likely it won't work in Pine versions previous 4.

Comment: But OP is saying that alerts work with his strategy and he indeed has strategy function calls. Interesting..

Comment: @Rbdm, care to share your full code? It is difficult to help with that piece of information you gave us.

Comment: @BarisYakut yes, I am confused too. @Rbdm is it Strategy script with `strategy` function in it?

Comment: @Michel_T. I know V2 is old, but this is an old and rather long script and making a V4 version takes quite some time. V2 is working fine aside from this. So anyway, I run the strategy version on my backtester and the study version with the alerts on a VPS; the point of my question is, why doesn't strategy.position_avg_price function work properly? Some of the signals are right, many other are wrong or missing.

Comment: @BarisYakut I run the strategy version on my backtester and the study version with the alerts on a VPS; the point of my question is, why doesn't strategy.position_avg_price function work properly? Some of the signals are right, many other are wrong or missing.

Comment: @Rbdm the param is called `position_avg_price` and it returns average price of an asset in your position. It's not entry price.